# jQuery find() -- loop through found elements?

Tags: jquery, find

I'm attempting to apply some CSS to a set of elements using a `data` attribute each of them has. I'm going through the elements using jQuery's `find`, but I can't seem to use `$(this)` to apply any bespoke transformations to the individual elements:

```
$('#ajax-list').find('a .title').css('background', colours[$(this).attr('data-colour-id')]);
```

I'm trying to use `$(this)` to refer to `a .title` but it's not working. Is there a way to loop through the results of `find()` to affect each found element individually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [.css( propertyName, function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value) format to achieve this

```
$('#ajax-list').find('a .title').css('background', function(){
    return colours[$(this).attr('data-colour-id')];
});
```

Comment: +1 I would have used `each()`.  Thanks for teaching me my daily new thing :)

Comment: @Archer same here. Very useful to know!